# Calculating the arithmetic mean (average) of two numbers: what's the meaning of optimizations?

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, average, mean

I noticed that in .NET, `Array.BinarySearch(Array array, Object value)` method uses the  [following implementation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs#625) for calculating the average of two numbers:

```
private static int GetMedian(int low, int hi)
{
    return low + ((hi - low) >> 1);
}
```

I have two questions about this implementation:

1. Why arithmetic shift operator used explicitly? Isn't it a compiler job to optimize division by 2 by replacing it with the arithmetic shift?
2. Why not simply `return (low + hi) >> 1;`?

Comment: Perhaps the very same code is used not only in the normal .NET framework with a full JIT compiler but also .NET Micro where this sort of optimisation could make things faster.

Comment: Additionally, when `low` and `hi` is 1 apart, `>> 1` and `/ 2` will produce different results. It may be that one result is better than the other (perhaps only in the eyes of that programmer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Not sure, but there's no harm in it, either.
2. It's to prevent the [binary search bug](http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html) from occurring.

Comment: That's only the answer to the second half of the question, though.

Comment: interesting, according to the link that is the proper code in C to avoid overflow: `mid = ((unsigned int)low + (unsigned int)high)) >> 1;` do you know why OPs code omits the casts?

Comment: @thumbmunkeys: (a) it's not C, (b) why do a conversion when you can just subtract and get the same result?

Comment: @Joey thanks. I do realize that it is not C. You're right, now that I think of it, I see the casts are not necessary

Answer (score 1):

1. No reason. Maybe to make sure that compiler does job good.
2. To avoid arithmetic overflow when `(low + hi) > int.MaxValue`.

Answer (score 0):

1. The programmer preferred to use optimal code already.
2. (low + hi) could result in an integer overflow.